# Java Date getHours() and display in Angular page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, jhipster

When I click the **Create new Ticket** #1, 
I'm able to automatically display the current year/month/day as show here: [image] But I need the time aswell.

Here is how I've implemeted it:

**My Java Pojo:**

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "jhi_date")
    private LocalDate date;

//getters and setters
}
```

My ticket-popup.service.ts

```
setTimeout(() => {

                  // populate date with current date if new
                    const tickets = new Ticket();
                    const now = new Date();
                    tickets.date = {
                        year: now.getFullYear(), // works fine
                        month: now.getMonth() + 1, // works fine
                        day: now.getDate(), // works fine
                       time: now.getTime(), // doesnt return anything as shown in image
                       hour: now.getHours() // doesnt return anything as in image
                    };

                    this.ngbModalRef = this.ticketModalRef(component, tickets);
                    resolve(this.ngbModalRef);
                }, 0);
```

It's most probably caused by the `ngbDatepicker` component. What could be it's equivalent to replace ?

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="field_date">Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="field_date" type="text" class="form-control" name="date" ngbDatepicker  #dateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="ticket.date"
                />
                <span class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="dateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Github sample [here](https://github.com/Georges73/Ticket)

Comment: Show us the html for the input.  I'm curious if it's `type="date"`.

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez check my github link . It's Jhipste by the way

Comment: In you github link it looks like you have ngbDatePicker directive on the input. So that's probably controlling the formatting.  I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right place.

Comment: ngbDatepicker seems to be the right place to look. I'll play around. Thank you

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez I managed to get the time. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get the time:

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable {

 //@Column(name = "jhi_date") 
 //private LocalDate date;
 @Column(name = "jhi_timestamp")
 private ZonedDateTime timestamp; // used ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDate 

//getters and setters
}
```

Used Angular Date Pipe in **My ticket-popup.service.ts**

```
setTimeout(() => {

                  // populate date/time with current time if new
                    const ticket = new Ticket();
                    ticket.timestamp = this.datePipe // used Pipe date format 
                        .transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm');


                    this.ngbModalRef = this.ticketModalRef(component,  ticket);
                    resolve(this.ngbModalRef);
                }, 0);
```

Got rid of **ngbDatepicker** from 
**ticket-dialog.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="field_timestamp">Timestamp</label>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <input id="field_timestamp" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="timestamp" [(ngModel)]="ticket.timestamp"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
```

result:

[image]